# dropdownlist doesn't reset on page reload

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, reload

Hey,...very simple question

I usually write php but happen to be programming with ASP.NET 3.0 framework now and can't figure out how to fix this.

I have a DropdownList and if I selected a some value,...my code behind does a bunch of stuff and outputs the data......

Now,...if I reload the page (ie. press F5 or the little reload thing on the browser)....all my data resets as if my selectedIndex is 0....but the actual showing Value is the previous one I selected!...i try to reset the index in my code behind in the "if ispostback = false" statement...but nothing works......it's like the Value is cached and nothing I can do changes it...

...any help would be appreciated :)

(further explanation: ....if print to screen a mydropdownlist.selectedIndex from my Page load Sub...It will return a 0....however the selected index on the screen is clearly not the 0 one....I understand WHY this is happening...i just need to stop it....or at least have a way of determining the index in the view state...)

Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal behaviour for form fields. Browsers generally try to remember the contents of text fields, the states of checkboxes and the selected items in dropdowns over events like page reload and back/forwards.

For this reason you should not assume during script initialisation that the values of your form fields will match the content you served up in the HTML. Have the script sniff their current values and set its variables and DOM state up accordingly when the page loads.

If you really want to throw away all user form field changes on reload/navigation, call [form.reset()](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76767677) in the script initialisation to return it to the HTML state. But this can be quite user-unfriendly in normal circumstances.

Comment: The problem is when I try to retried dropdownlist.SelectedIndex from my dropdownlist in my page load it THINKS it's 0....not what is it actually showing. 

...do you mean call form.reset() from javasript or code behind? ...(do I have to use a form?)

Comment: From JavaScript. If you access SelectedIndex from codebehind, you are changing the HTML before it gets as far as the browser; you have no input into what the browser does after getting the HTML.

Comment: oh, thanks, good to know...if you dont' mind me asking how would i do this: "Have the script sniff their current values and set its variables and DOM state up accordingly when the page loads."

Comment: Well, just that if you've got any client-side JavaScript stuff that has state, it shouldn't assume that the initial state is what you served to it via HTML. If you're not using client-side script you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: my contractor is using a masterpage...and thus i needed to use a document.<%=form1.CLientID %>.reset() ....but taht worked perfectly,..thanks

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like when you hit f5 you are NOT doing a new page reload.  You say that when you select something from your dropdownlist that you do a bunch code behind stuff.  Well that action IS a postback.  So hitting f5 AFTER that action would not be considered a new call to the page so the the if (IsPostBack == false) would fail because it is a postback.

Your first action caused it to be a postback so hitting f5 after that, will be a postback.

It sounds like you may have some viewstate issues as well since your other controls are resetting.  Although if you are doing the hide / shows with client side scripting, they will not be persisted through the viewstate anyways.

Comment: Ummm no. I know this is old but why don`t you try running this through the debugger before commenting? If you hit f5 or the refresh icon, it is NOT considered a postback.

Comment: @user3302828 If you page has just done a postback, and you press the refresh button, it WILL be a postback.  If you just had a regular page load and did a refresh it would not be.  Please read what my answer was as I thought that was pretty clear.  And yes this is old...

Comment: No matter when I hit refresh on my browser (doesn`t matter if I just did 27 postbacks from other controls or not), a refresh action NEVER registers as a postback for me. Can you post an example of where pressing refresh does register as a postback for you? Thanks!

Comment: @user3302828 maybe ask a question...  I really don't feel like pursuing this since I know how it works but someone may want to help you understand.

Comment: are you certain that is how it works, as in you can verify 100% right now that a refresh is unequivocally a postback when done after a postback? Because I ran into a similar issue mentioned in the OP and I can tell you after running things though the debugger for an hour I have never been able to see a "refresh" recognized as postback no matter what else I was doing on the page.

Comment: @user3302828 yes... 100% I do this often to test a 'postback' over and over...  All the refresh button is doing is sending the EXACT same request again which was a postback the first time, so refreshing the page just causes the same action to occur, the server doesn't treat it differently so your app will see it as a postback... sheesh I better get an upvote for this lol.

Comment: haha ok I will take your word for it then. I personally can never get it to register a postback, presumably through use of update panels and ninja-ing my page to finish loading before I can move my mouse up to the refresh button.

Comment: @Kelsey you are describing exactly the issue I'm having, but I don't know how to understand this. In my case I select something in a drop-down which filters a gridview. I then hit refresh and it re-populates a gridview with the default list, *then* sets the combo up to the value I selected - so gridview and combo don't match. Could you post a reference that explains this? (I also disable textboxes just before a postback to block further editing, and those textboxes are re-disabled when the page reloads - only fix I could find is manually iterate them and undisable on jquery load.)

Comment: PS. This is my first proper experience of ASP web controls but I've been doing web development for decades, so this viewstate is right at the heart heart of a lot of general bafflement! Can post as a question if you want to write a non-comment answer.

Comment: I can add `EnableViewState="false" ViewStateMode="Disabled"` but still, when I refresh, the gridview resets, but the combo returns to the non-default value. (If I click in the browser URL box and enter, so a plain `GET` of the URL, everything resets correctly.) Indeed disabling viewstate leads to a nasty bug whereby selecting the default combo item calls the postback, receives a 200 response, but the gridview no longer updates - until I clear my session. I'm finding that really weird.

Comment: Posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306914/asp-net-viewstate-bug-updating-some-controls-incorrectly-and-not-others)

Answer (score 1):

Try [disabling veiwstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate.aspx) on the checkbox if you don't need it.

Comment: Yes, that's expected. You have to repopulate your list each time.

Comment: ya,...but the involves another database query in my particular case,..but it's a good option to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clearing the cache in your browser?  Most browsers support Control+F5 as a hard-refresh that will clear the cache for the current page and reload the entire page from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings,
I too am trying to clear a drop-down list once a value from the other drop-down is selected. When the user goes to submit the form, there should be only one drop-down which has a value. I have started the code as shown below but the drop-down will not reset itself when a value from the other drop-down is selected. I'm sure I'm missing something very simple or my naming is off. Thanks.

```
enter code
```

`<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="homepagestate.aspx.cs" inherits="_homepagestate"%>

```
< form id="form1" runat="server">
```

< asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="sel">
            < asp:ListItem Value="-Select one or more states-">< /asp:ListItem>
            < asp:ListItem Value="ALABAMA">< /asp:ListItem>

```
    < /asp:DropDownList>
```

< asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
          < asp:ListItem Value="-Select One-">< /asp:ListItem>
          < /asp:DropDownList>

```
      < asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" /></div>
</form>
```

using System;

using System.Data;

using System.Configuration;

using System.Collections;

using System.Web;

using System.Web.Security;

using System.Web.UI;

using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class _homepagestate : System.Web.UI.Page

{

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    if ( !IsPostBack )

    {

       // sel();

        DropDownList2.SelectedIndex = 0;

    }
```

}

```
protected void sel(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    Response.Write(DropDownList2.SelectedIndex);

    //DropDownList2.selecteditem = 0;

}
```

}

'

Answer (score 0):

This is actually from parrkid on a different stackoverflow question, but add this at the end of your page:

```
<script language="javascript">
  var B01 = document.getElementById('<%=YourDropDownList.ClientID%>');
  B01.selectedIndex = 0;
</script>
```

Yep...total hack for what's probably an asp.net but IMHO :-P